# Adding focus state to container with embedded link

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have an Angular ng-repeat that creates boxes and returns a container with a little info. I have the hover effect working, but am struggling getting the focus to work. Basically, these containers are allowed to be clicked, then show a larger box with additional info. Showing my code below. Ideas please?

html:

```
<h1>Pending Swipes</h1>
<div class="swipeBoxes" ng-repeat="swipe in swipes" ng-required="true">
    <a href="" ng-click="editSwipe(swipe)" >
        <div class="swipeBox col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimLine" style="width: 3px; position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px;">{{ $index + 1 }}.</span>
                <span class="claimedLeft">swipe date:</span>
                <span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimedLeft">provider:</span
                ><span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.merchant }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimedLeft">amount:</span>
                <span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.amount | currency }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the css is to make this work kinda:

```
.swipeBoxes a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.swipeBoxes a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.swipeBox, .recurBox {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 85px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #000000;
}

.swipeBox:hover, .swipeBox:active, .swipeBox:focus {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

.swipeBox >a:active, .swipeBox >a:focus {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Comment: can you create a [workable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the behavior in question?

Answer (score 0):

The `:focus` selector is only allowed on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs.

So it will work on `a` elements but not on `div`.

Your css rule:

```
.swipeBox >a:active, .swipeBox >a:focus {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

is not working because you have no `a` element as first child of `.swipeBox`

Comment: FYI: Elements such as divs can be _made_ “focusable”, by using the [`tabindex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) attribute.

Comment: @CBroe -  The tabindex seems to make sense, but I cannot seem to get it to work with focus. Seem on the documentation, simply have that attribute it would allow for my css to work.

Comment: Looks like other way, going to need to go with jquery as I thought css could now handle this. So a simple child select function with jquery would do it.

Comment: Do you just want to indicate which element is selected?Because showing a border around the selected element is not very pretty... :D Instead you could change the whole backgroundcolor, make the Element slightly bigger and so on